# Convert SortedList to IOrderedEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently having trouble finding a way to get an IOrderedEnumerable from a SortedList.

I have a complex type, we'll just call it 'A' for now, that can be decomposed into an enumerable of type 'A'. I'm currently creating a SortedList in a recursive decomposition function where the key, an `int`, is related to the order the piece was decomposed in:

```
private static SortedList<int, A> RecursivelyBuildMySortedList(A myValue)
{
    if (myValue == StopCondition())
    {
        return new SortedList<int, A> { { 1, myValue } };
    }

    var left = RecursivelyBuildMySortedList(myValue.Left);
    var right = RecursivelyBuildMySortedList(myValue.Right).Select(entry => new KeyValuePair<int, A>(entry.Key + left.Count, entry.Value)).ToList();
    right.ForEach(pair => left.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value));
    return left;
}
```

However, I don't want to expose the SortedList to consumers since the value of the key, related to decomposition order, has little meaning to consumers (especially as an `int`). The only thing a consumer needs to care about is what the final ordering of the pieces was so that each piece can be processed in the correct order. I would prefer to expose an IOrderedEnumerable to consumers. I thought this would be a fairly simple task since a SortedList is in many ways very similar to an OrderedEnumerable, but I've not been able to find a good conversion yet:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<A> Decompose(A myValue)
{
    SortedList<int, A> mySortedList = RecursivelyBuildMySortedList(myValue);

    // Can't find a way to preserve the order of the objects during 'OrderBy'
    // mySortedList.Select(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value).OrderBy(obj => obj.index);

    // The select statement would not match the return type that promises IOrderedEnumerable
    // mySortedList.OrderBy(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Key).Select(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value);

}
```

Does anyone have a method for extracting an IOrderedEnumerable from a SortedList for consumption? As a side note, I'm aware that:

```
return mySortedList.Select(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value);
```

Would return an IEnumerable that would preserve order 'under the hood', but due to how important the order in which the enumerable is processed is, I would rather the return type be descriptive enough to convey that the underlying collection is ordered (to make the API more readable).

Comment: Why does it _have_ to be coverted to an `IOrderedEnumerable<>`? There really shouldn't be any need.  You know `SortedList<,>` is sorted...

Comment: I think you should go with `IEnumerable` and add a comment to the function how the result is sorted. Returning `IOrderedEnumerable` doesn't really tell the consumer anything about how the collections is ordered anyway.

Comment: @JeffMercado, because exposing the key that was used to sort the elements is meaningless to consumers and I was hoping to clean up my presentation of the result. To phrase the question a different way, if 'Decompose' was a function that prime factored an integer and returned the factors in the order they were discovered, the resulting 'key' in the sorted the list (the order that factor was discovered in), would be meaningless once the result was obtained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Values propery of the SortedList:

```
  private IOrderedEnumerable<string> GetResults() {
     SortedList<int, string> list = new SortedList<int, string>();
     list.Add(40, "Mehrzad");
     list.Add(20, "Chehraz");
     return list.Values.OrderBy(key => 0);         
  }
```

And then use:

```
 IOrderedEnumerable<string> enumerable = GetResults();
 foreach (var item in enumerable) {
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item);
 }
```

It works since OrderBy (key => 0) returns values in their original order which are sorted by the SortedList.

Or you may implement IOrderedEnumerable (My old answer):

```
class OrderedEnumerableWithoutKey<TKey, TValue> : IOrderedEnumerable<TValue> {
     private IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> inner;
     public OrderedEnumerableWithoutKey(IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> inner) {
        this.inner = inner;
     }
     public IOrderedEnumerable<TValue> CreateOrderedEnumerable<TKey1>(Func<TValue, TKey1> keySelector, IComparer<TKey1> comparer, bool descending) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
     public IEnumerator<TValue> GetEnumerator() {
        return new Enumerator(inner.GetEnumerator());
     }
     IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return new Enumerator(inner.GetEnumerator());
     }
     class Enumerator : IEnumerator<TValue> {
        private IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> inner;
        public Enumerator(IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> inner) {
           this.inner = inner;
        }
        public TValue Current {
           get {
              return inner.Current.Value;
           }
        }
        object IEnumerator.Current {
           get {
              return inner.Current.Value;
           }
        }
        public void Dispose() {
           this.inner.Dispose();
        }
        public bool MoveNext() {
           return this.inner.MoveNext();
        }
        public void Reset() {
           this.inner.Reset();
        }
     }
  }
```

Then use it in that way:

```
private IOrderedEnumerable<string> GetResults() {
     SortedList<int, string> list = new SortedList<int, string>();
     list.Add(20, "Mehrzad");
     list.Add(10, "Chehraz");
     return new OrderedEnumerableWithoutKey<int, string>(list.OrderBy(item => item.Key));    }
..
..
// Consumer part:
IOrderedEnumerable<string> enumerable = GetResults();
foreach (var item in enumerable) {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item);
}
// Outputs:
// Cherhaz
// Mehrzad
```

Comment: Your `OrderedEnumerableWithoutKey` will explode when `GetResults().ThenB(..)` is called. It isn't a intuitive thing for called. And `list.Values.OrderBy(key => 0)` is ordering the list which is ordered already. It is not a problem as per se; but could be inefficient if the sorted list is huge.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I agree that my answers may not be the best ones, and I'll remove this if any better answer was found.

Comment: I hope mine is better :p

Comment: Yea, maybe :D Let the asker judge that!

Comment: Your second answer works since OrderBy is stable (may be helpful to include that fact in answer). Very clever!

Comment: @LiamK You are right, I added the note.

Answer (score 2):

There is no public implementation of `IOrderedEnumerable` available. You'll have to roll your own.

It is fairly simple to do with the help of `Enumerable.OrderBy` and `Enumerable.OrderByDescending`. With minimal possible code, see the implementation below.

```
public class SortedListOrderedEnumerable<TKey, TValue> : IOrderedEnumerable<TValue>
{
    private readonly SortedList<TKey, TValue> innerList;
    public SortedListOrderedEnumerable(SortedList<TKey, TValue> innerList)
    {
        this.innerList = innerList;
    }

    public IOrderedEnumerable<TValue> CreateOrderedEnumerable<TKey1>(Func<TValue, TKey1> keySelector, IComparer<TKey1> comparer, bool @descending)
    {
        return @descending 
            ? innerList.Values.OrderByDescending(keySelector, comparer) 
            : innerList.Values.OrderBy(keySelector, comparer);
    }

    public IEnumerator<TValue> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return innerList.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public static class Ext
{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TValue> AsOrderedEnumerable<TKey, TValue>(
        this SortedList<TKey, TValue> list)
    {
        return new SortedListOrderedEnumerable<TKey, TValue>(list);
    } 
}
```

Then use it as

```
SortedList<int, string> list = new SortedList<int, string>();
...
var ordered = list.AsOrderedEnumerable()
    .ThenBy(...)
    .ThenByDescending(...);
```

Now your Decompose method will become

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<A> Decompose(A myValue)
{
    SortedList<int, A> mySortedList = RecursivelyBuildMySortedList(myValue);        
    return mySortedList.AsOrderedEnumerable();
}
```

Edit: Updated my initial answer to return `IOrderedEnumerable<TValue>`, in original answer it was `IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`

Comment: Clean implentation. @MehrzadChehraz was able to give an answer that didn't require me to implement my own interface, but this was also suitable.

Comment: @LiamK Yes. But that's inefficient as it is ordering a list which is already ordered. For small lists this is fine; If the list is huge, it is not. Depending upon that, you can decide to use it.

Comment: Fair point. I went with the other answer because the resulting enumerable will only ever contain between 1 and 3 elements.

Answer (score 1):

You likely don't want to use `IOrderedEnumerable` for this.

`IOrderedEnumerable` exists solely for things like `ThenBy(...)` where you're dynamically specifying the sort order at run time (really, just building a comparer).

`SortedList` on the other hand has a constant sort order and comparer -- its ordering can not change.

I suggest sticking to plain `IEnumerable` unless you've got a good reason you haven't yet stated. Remember, interfaces aren't there to document a type (i.e. by saying "this is ordered"). They're there to expose functionality.